# Set check state in other application's CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, pinvoke, invoke, platform, checkedlistbox

Okay so i've been using P/invoke for quite a long time now, but i came across a problem google doesn't answer.

A program i use contains a CheckedListBox. When i inspect the object, WinspectorSPY shows it as a "ListBox" though. But all options in the listbox contain a checkbox within the line.

How do i check one of the checkboxes from my C# program using P/invoke? Is this even possible? I messed around with gettext/settext and checkbox messages, but since this is a "checkbox within a listbox", this doesn't help me any further.

[image: This is the target CheckedListBox]

Comment: That is accurate, CheckedListBox is in fact a native Windows LISTBOX control.  It overrides ListBox.OnDrawItem() to display the checkboxes.  It just *looks* like a checkbox, painted, it is not a real one.  The native control knows beans about it so faking it with a message is not simple.  It has an accessibility provider so standard advice applies, use the System.Windows.Automation namespace.

Comment: And then what should i do with System.Windows.Automation? I'm not an advanced coder yet, i just know how to use P/invoke. Could you elaborate?

Comment: In the meantime i found out how Automation works. However, is it possible to SET attributes? I know how to read them now, but that doesn't really help me any further...

Comment: Yes it is possible. Spend some time learning UI Automation.